# Mime error with Angular 8 in Firebase Hosting

Tags: angular, firebase, electron, firebase-hosting

I have an Angular 8 app that is being hosted on Firebase and is being ran on the client side by: [Go-Astilectron](https://github.com/asticode/go-astilectron) (Astilectron 0.30 and Electron 4.0.1).

The thing is that I am getting the error below in some of my clients (it happens just as the Angular code is loading, so the Astilectron just displays a blank page):

```
Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
main-es2015.5a90aaf45a8347384655.js:1 

Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

In some cases we managed to solve this by just reloading the page, but in others no matter what I do, the page doesn't load.

I've done some research and found that this might be releated to the application registering a service worker, but this is not my case.

Also, since I am servince a static site using Firebase Hosting, I didn't made any MIME configurations.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Be sure that in `index.html` the `head` includes:

```
<base href="/">
```

See: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10325#issuecomment-399329033

This error also occurs when running Python servers on Windows machines where the Registry mime types are not set correctly.

See: https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/1045#issuecomment-42202749

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! My index.html does have `<base href="/">`. I will check the registry of the affected machines

Comment: Hi, I've checked and this computer's registry seems fine. I didn't find any entry with text/plain.

Comment: Hi there, just added this part in, and the problem consists. A funny thing is my dev branch works perfectly fine while my prod branch breaks for no reason.

Comment: @Felipe Hi there, did you find the solution to this problem?

Comment: Hey @TerryWindwalker, yes. If I remember correctly the problem was in the Windows Registry as per this link: https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/1045#issuecomment-42202749 that Cristopher shared.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue.

Go to angular.js and check the value of "outputPath". If it's set to something like "dist/your-project-name" try changing it to "dist/", redeploy and then do a hard refresh (Ctrl+F5) of your site.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by simply running `npm cache clear -f` then refreshing the browser.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For me, **Empty cache and hard reload** of the browser has solved the problem.